# How to convert from .wav (hydrophone data) to pressure (SPL)?

Tags: matlab, sound

I am new here, since I started recently with signal processing. I am trying to analyze a .wav file recorded by a **hydrophone**, however, I need to convert it to **SPL**. I have a **calibration file** which contains 2 columns one with the center frequency of each bin and another with sensitivity calibration for each bin (dB re counts/uPa). How could I use this?

Edited: more characteristics of the hydrophone, the hydrophone I am using is **LF** (Low Frequency), therefore, the characteristics are **LF** column.

[image]

And here is the instrument sensitivity curve:

[image]

Comment: How is your data stored, what units does it have?

Comment: It is a .wav file, I am not sure what units does it have.

Comment: It it’s in the wave file then you need to know the offset/sensitivity. If you don’t have it, then it’s rather impossible to obtain the actual SPL. For example if you have another recording done with the same setup and you know exactly what is the level of that signal, you could calibrate it. Unless the software is saving WAV in some specific ways.

Comment: IMPORTANT INFORMATION: Apparently with some research I came across that my device goes from -3V to +3V and the units of my signal are bits. Therefore, full scale would be 2^(24-1) since it is recorded in 24 bit. Now I can translate my .wav to Volts.